# Accessing API on different domain with CORS

Tags: wcf, api, post, http-headers, cors

I am working on a self-hosted WCF service with some GET and POST methods,

*For Example*

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
public string HelloWorld(){
    ....
}

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
public string GetMessage(string username){
    ....
}
```

when accessing those services on the client side which is hosted on different domain, I have got the following error

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:57805' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

After researching on the Internet, I figured that the error can be resolved by putting the following codes in each WCF function

```
  WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Method == "OPTIONS")
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Header", "Content-Type, Accept, SOAPAction");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
        }
```

Now this block of code is working great for a **GET** method, so I can see there is "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" added into the response header. However it does not work for a **POST** method somehow as the response header has no change at all.

Does anyone have an idea why it is not working for a **POST** method?
I have changed the GetMessage to be a **GET** method, the response header worked immediately but not when I changed it back to **POST**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved!!

The code works great for both **GET** and **POST**, however the web service throw the following error for my **POST** function, therefore it causes a failure.

> The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the
>   Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty = true).

By changing the BodyStyle for the function to WrappedResponse, the error gone and the function can be accessed outside the domain

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse)]
    Booking CreateNewBooking(int divisionId);
```